# Getting an error when running the glmnet function in R

Tags: r, error-handling, logistic-regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am working with a high-dimensional data `nxp` is equal to `10 x 4172`. My data is a gene expression data where my response variable Y is binary response variable. I am trying to apply logistic regression with the lasso penalty using the `glment` package error in R however an error is being prompted.

I have tried fitting the glmnet package by removing just 1 observation but same error was provided. I am assuming that the reason for this is due to very small sample size but I cannot increase the sample size as that was provided to me. The code is as per below:

```
> dim(Data)
[1]   10 4172
> tabyl(Data$Group)
 Data$Group n percent
          0 6     0.6
          1 4     0.4
> levels(Data$Group)
[1] "0" "1"

set.seed(3456)
x <- model.matrix(Group~.,Data[-1,])[,-1]
y <- Data[-1,]$Group

lasso.model <- glmnet(x,y,alpha = 1, family = 'binomial')
```

The error being prompted is as per below:

```
Warning message:
In lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground
```

I tried to use the below link as a refrence but it is not the same package:

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/111348/

Comment: A warning is not an error. The distinction between these two is important to keep in mind. The warning is of a statistical nature, indicating that you might not have a sufficient number of observations of a particular class in order to produce useful results.

Comment: @lmo - oh ok thanks a lot! So I can proceed with this but obviously remark this warning.